# Batch file to parse .txt files online

Tags: batch-file

I have .txt files created on our server and can access them with url links.

On the page is "Last Scanned: 08/01/17 03:58"

I have about 300 urls like this and I want to be able to make sure the date is correct on each page. When the date is not correct it means the file didn't get a report to it.

The url to the file has the date in it like this:

http://noc.mysite.com/cmoc/ftpdata/logs/daily_status_reports/ABFDBC01D01_01.txt

The 01 at the end of the url means this month but the first of the month. if you change the number to 13 it means this month and the 13th date.

anyway I'm hoping there's a good way to run a batch file, it goes to each url and tells me if the date matches. Having a different batch file for each day is ok.

so if I'm running the file for the 01 of the month like today, I'm hoping it will create a text file with:
08/01/17
08/01/17
08/01/17
08/01/17
08/01/17
08/01/17
07/22/17
08/01/17
08/01/17

so in the example above you can see how one them stopped reporting on the 22nd of last month.

I've learned how to open each url in a batch file which has actually been helpful like one click and I open 300 book marks.

But now I'm looking to scan on the page for the words last scanned and have it tell me what comes after for the next say 8 characters on the same line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is a bit broad.. examples would help.. also, have you considered PowerShell or shell scripts?

Comment: There is no need to consider a potential selection of scripting languages. The only tasks required at the moment is to determine the parameters of the question and to see the code you have developed and researched so far. When you have those try [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45447758/edit) your question appropriately. If you don't, I'd wager that you will struggle to receive reasonable responses.